# Does this sequence have a convergent subsequence whose natural density is $1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)_n$ be non-negative real sequence and
$$
S_\epsilon = \{n \mid a_n > \epsilon\} \quad (\epsilon > 0).
$$

If the [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of $S_\epsilon$ is $0$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, does the sequence $(a_n)_n$ have a subsequence that converges to zero and whose natural density is $1$ ?

Comment: You mean a subsequence $a_{n_k}\to 0$ and the natural density of $n_k$ is $1$ ?

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc Yes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_k=\{n\,:\, a_n\ge {1\over k}\}.$ Consider $R_k=\mathbb{N}\setminus S_k.$ The natural density of $R_k$ is $1.$  Hence there exists $n_1$ such that $${\# \{m\in R_1\,:\, 1\le m< n\}\over n}\ge {1\over 2},\qquad n\ge n_1.$$
Similarly there exists $n_2>n_1$ such that $${\# \{m\in R_2\,:\, n_1\le m< n\}\over n}\ge {2\over 3},\qquad n\ge n_2. $$ By proceeding so on there exists $n_k>n_{k-1}$ such that
$${\# \{m\in R_k\,:\, n_{k-1}\le m< n\}\over n}\ge {k\over k+1},\qquad n\ge n_k. $$
Let $\qquad $ $\displaystyle R=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \{m\in R_k\,:\, n_{k-1}\le m<n_{k+1}\}
=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty R_k\cap [n_{k-1},n_{k+1})$

We claim that  the subsequence  $\{a_n\,:\, n\in R\}$ is convergent to $0$ and the natural density of $R$ is equal $1.$

Observe that for $n\in R$ and $n\ge n_k$ we have $n\in R_l$ for some $l\ge k.$ Hence $a_n<{1\over l}\le {1\over k}.$ Therefore the limit of the subsequence is indeed equal $0.$
Furthermore let  $n_k\le n< n_{k+1}.$ Then
$$ {\# \{m\in R\,:\, 1\le m< n\}\over n}\ge  {\# \{m\in R_k\,:\, n_{k-1}\le m< n\}\over n}\ge {k\over k+1}$$
which implies
$$\lim_n {\# \{m\in R\,:\, 1\le m< n\}\over n}=1$$